# Installing message handler

Tags: c++, qt, logging

I have tried to create a log file for an application by installing a message handler using `qinstallMessageHandler()` function. My program is as follows:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <QtCore>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fd;

void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const char *msg)
{
    QString timeStamp = QTime::currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss:zzz");
    switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg:
        fprintf(fd, "[%s]", timeStamp.toStdString().c_str());
        fprintf(fd, "[Debug] %s\n", msg);
        break;
    case QtWarningMsg:
        fprintf(fd, "[%s]", timeStamp.toStdString().c_str());
        fprintf(fd, "[Warning] %s\n", msg);
        break;
    case QtCriticalMsg:
        fprintf(fd, "[%s]", timeStamp.toStdString().c_str());
        fprintf(fd, "[Critical] %s\n", msg);
        break;
    case QtFatalMsg:
        fprintf(fd, "[%s]", timeStamp.toStdString().c_str());
        fprintf(fd, "[Fatal] %s\n", msg);
        abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    fd = fopen("log.txt", "a");
    qInstallMessageHandler(myMessageOutput);

    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);



    qDebug()<<"\t Hello World!!! \n";

    return a.exec();
}
```

But after compiling I get the following error:

> error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(QtMsgType, const char*)' to 'QtMessageHandler {aka void (*)(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)}' [-fpermissive]

Anyone here who have faced the same problem earlier?

Comment: Check the list of arguments wanted by the message handler. It does not match your function (and the error message tells you *exactly* what's wanted, if you don't want to read the reference).

Comment: [See the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you switch to Qt5 and used the message handler function signature defined in Qt4.x. You need to declare your message handler as follows:

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type,
                     const QMessageLogContext &context,
                     const QString &msg)
{
    [..]
}
```

instead.

Comment: I entered that also but not using it,but it is showing error as:error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void (* qInstallMessageHandler(QtMessageHandler))(QtMsgType, const QMessageLogContext&, const QString&)' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Thanks buddy it was a silly mistake third parameter was required to be const QString &msg.